# Angular CLI configure scripts to load entire external javascript directory

Tags: angular, angular-cli, zurb-foundation-6

I'm attempting to load the `node_modules/foundation-sites` into my Angular CLI application.  The directory looks like this:

```
node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/css:
foundation.css                foundation-float.min.css  
foundation-prototype.css      foundation-rtl.css
foundation-float.css          foundation.min.css        
foundation-prototype.min.css  foundation-rtl.min.css

node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js:
foundation.d.ts  foundation.js  foundation.min.js  npm.js  plugins
```

I've attempted to use globbing in the `angular-cli.json` file:

```
"scripts": [
    { "glob": "**/*", "input": "../node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js", "output": "/js/" },
]
```

but this throws a :

`Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read at Error (native)`

How do I include the entire directory of JS files without typing them out one by one in the `scripts` array?